Error in `scale_color_manual()`: ! Continuous values supplied to discrete scale
Good afternoon!
I am learning R by using the "Quantitative Social Science Data with R. An Introduction" by Fogarty (2019), which provides data and codes to replicate the examples. All works well, but I repeatedly get an error with the scale_color_manual function:
setwd("")
simd <- read.csv("simd_small.csv")
names(simd)
simd <- subset(simd, !is.na(pct_depress))
p1 <- ggplot(data=simd) +
geom_point(mapping=aes(x=pct_employment_deprived, y=pct_depress,
color=urban), position="jitter")
p2 <- ggplot(data=simd) +
geom_point(mapping=aes(x=pct_employment_deprived, y=pct_depress,
color=urban), position="jitter") +
scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red"))
p3 <- ggplot(data=simd) +
geom_point(mapping=aes(x=pct_employment_deprived, y=pct_depress,
shape=urban), position="jitter")
p4 <- ggplot(data=simd) +
geom_point(mapping=aes(x=pct_employment_deprived, y=pct_depress,
color=urban), position="jitter") +
scale_color_grey()
library(gridExtra)
x11()
grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, p4, ncol=2, nrow=2)
Issue:
Error in scale_color_manual():
! Continuous values supplied to discrete scale.
ℹ Example values: 0, 0, 0, 0, and 0
Run rlang::last_trace() to see where the error occurred.
I checked existing dicussions (e.g., "scale_color_manual not working for assigning custermized color [duplicate]"), but they did not seem to directly answer my question.
Thank you for your time and support and apologies if the mistake is obvious.
